# C# Function Behaviour Is it Automatically a promise?

Tags: c#, winforms

As the question says , are functions in c# executed step by step ? or are they async?

from this code :

```
          public class foo {

             public int intFunction1(){
                    //Do Something
                   return 1;
             }

              public int intFunction2(){
                    //Do Something
                   return 2;
             }

              public void TriggerFunction() {
                  intFunction1();
                  intFunction2();
              }
          }
```

Now the question is , will intFunction2 be triggered even intFunction1 is not yet completed? or will it wait for intFunction1 to be Finished before executing intFunction2 ?

Comment: Can't you use the debugger to answer this yourself?

Comment: C# will do things in the order in which you tell it to do those things, unless you use asynchronous or multithreaded techniques.  You've written synchronous code, so it will be executed synchronously.  If you'd used async-await, or Task.Run(), or Parallel.Invoke(), or any of a number of other similar tools, then you might get asynchronous behavior, but that would be rather intentional.

Comment: I don't even know which close reason to use!

Comment: @Saruman: I vote to close questions like this as "too broad", because the question itself carries the implication that its author is so new to programming (or at least the language in question), that any sufficiently detailed answer would involve extensive rudimentary "introduction to programming" information. The alternative would be to engage in a lengthy back and forth with the author, to ascertain what they do and do not know yet. Either way, there's no way to constrain the response sufficiently to be appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @PeterDuniho thanks for the info and advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly tell the compiler about your functions being [async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443(v=vs.120).aspx)

```
public async Task<int>  intFunction1() {...}
public async Task<int>  intFunction2() {...}
```

Now the function would be asynchronous as long as you have a `await` in the function definition somewhere (i.e. you call some other asynchronous function)

For eg:

```
public async Task<int> intFunction1() { return 5; }
```

is still synchronous and the control wouldn't move to next statement unless the function returns.
However this is asynchronous:

```
public async Task<int> intFunction1() { await Task.Delay(1000);return 5; }
```

Demo here: https://ideone.com/xQ03BV

Comment: I am not convinced that a person who does not already know that program statements execute sequentially, would be able to do _anything_ useful whatsoever with any sort of information explaining `async`/`await` or other asynchronous programming techniques.